# Use multiple custom fonts using @font-face?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I'm sure I'm missing something really straight forward. Been using a single custom font with normal font face:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: CustomFont;
    src: url('CustomFont.ttf');
}
```

All works fine when I use it but if I want to add another custom font what do I do? I've tried separating by comma the next one or adding a whole other font face but can't get the second font working.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You simply add another `@font-face` rule:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: CustomFont;
    src: url('CustomFont.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: CustomFont2;
    src: url('CustomFont2.ttf');
}
```

If your second font still doesn't work, make sure you're spelling its typeface name and its file name correctly, your browser caches are behaving, your OS isn't messing around with a font of the same name, etc.

Comment: Thanks, working now, turns out I was making a tiny syntactic error when I tried that out.

Answer (score 8):

I use this method in my css file

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: FontName1;
  src: url("fontname1.eot"); /* IE */
  src: local('FontName1'), url('fontname1.ttf') format('truetype'); /* others */
}
@font-face {
  font-family: FontName2;
  src: url("fontname1.eot"); /* IE */
  src: local('FontName2'), url('fontname2.ttf') format('truetype'); /* others */
}
@font-face {
  font-family: FontName3;
  src: url("fontname1.eot"); /* IE */
  src: local('FontName3'), url('fontname3.ttf') format('truetype'); /* others */
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are having a problem with the font working I have also had this in the past and the issue I found was down to the **font-family:** name. This had to match what font name was actually given.

The easiest way I found to find this out was to install the font and see what display name is given.

For example, I was using Gill Sans on one project, but the actual font was called Gill Sans MT. Spacing and capitlisation was also important to get right.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/). They have a web font generator, which will also spit out a suitable stylesheet for your font (look for "@font-face kit"). This stylesheet can be included in your own, or you can use it as a template.

Answer (score 3):

You can use multiple font faces quite easily. Below is an example of how I used it in the past:

```html
<!--[if (IE)]><!-->
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Century Schoolbook";
            src: url(/fonts/century-schoolbook.eot);
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Chalkduster";
            src: url(/fonts/chalkduster.eot);
        }
    </style>
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE)]><!-->
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Century Schoolbook";
            src: url(/fonts/century-schoolbook.ttf);
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Chalkduster";
            src: url(/fonts/chalkduster.ttf);
        }
    </style>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

It is worth noting that fonts can be funny across different Browsers. Font face on earlier browsers works, but you need to use eot files instead of ttf.

That is why I include my fonts in the head of the html file as I can then use conditional IE tags to use eot or ttf files accordingly.

If you need to convert ttf to eot for this purpose there is a brilliant website you can do this for free online, which can be found at http://ttf2eot.sebastiankippe.com/.

Hope that helps.