# Two css iconfont not work in the same project

Tags: css

I have two CSS files each have a declaration of @ fontface with different fonts when I use them together on the same project, one of the fonts does not work. help me please?

Comment: Post your code. We can't help you without knowing what you're doing, "it doesn't work" is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you could give an example, maybe attach a fiddle with the problem, or tell us any errors you find (if there are any), or with what browsers this issue is happening on, I'd be happy to help! But without any more information, I'm kind of shooting in the dark :)

But here is an example of another stack overflow question and answer with two @font-faces which might help out:

[Multiple font-face in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872592/multiple-font-face-in-css)

[Use multiple custom fonts using @font-face?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018535/use-multiple-custom-fonts-using-font-face)